# How to add custom marker to here map route using the url

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to add custom marker to the hero maps route url, which will get the location attributes as payload.
I am expecting a solution which will reduce the usage of packages and can be just solved using the correct url.
For example: https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/mapview

Answer (score 0):

the API endpoint you shared is the Map Image API which support showing POI markers. You can custom the marker's type, theme, color, or size by referring to the documentation at https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/map-image-developer-guide/page/topics/resource-map.html